# Allow Nullable Model in Views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nullable, visual-studio-2019

The compiler *appears* to show an error when using a `struct`/ `enum` or any other **value** type as my MVC Model.

> CS0037    Cannot convert null to 'MyEnum' because it is a non-nullable
>   value type

I created a new MVC project (in VS 2019), created an enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

and put it as model in the "About" view:

[image]

Why is that occurring?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The compiler appears to show a error when using a struct / value type
>   as my MVC Model.

As per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709863/asp-net-mvc-viewmodel-should-be-class-or-struct), the model can definitely be *either* a `class` or a `struct`. There are pros and cons, but both **are allowed**.

So, why are you seeing this error then? 
The short answer is - this is not a real error. **It is a fake error**.

Visual Studio sometimes shows fake errors, particularly when the dropdown in `Error List` is set to `Build + Intellisense` (rather than `Build Only`).

My suggestion to you is to switch the dropdown to be `Build Only`. *In my projects, Intellisense gives a number of fake errors hence why I leave it in `Build Only` mode most of the time.*

*It occurs in Visual Studio 2017 and 2019. I have not tested it elsewhere.*

Comment: Can confirm it happens in VS 2022, which sent me on a google-spree, and found your answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem passing a decimal model to a view. I suffixed the decimal type with the nullable '?' operator:

```
@model decimal?
```